# BroadcastReceiver does not receive broadcast

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

My BroadcastReceiver does not receive anything. Most likely its my setup that is wrong, because I was not able to find any good examples on this. I need my receiver to receive something in my MainActivity, and change a View. I have almost the same code in an Android project, and here it is working, however BroadcastReceivers seems to be implemented a tiny bit differently in Xamarin (in Android, I can make a new BroadcastReceiver almost like an object, but in Xamarin, or C#, it seems I must make my own class and thus do not have the same possibilities to directly reference the views). If I get this to work, I will post a full working example for everyone too.

Here is how I have tried to set it up:

```
[Activity(Label = "GetLocation.Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button button;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // ... various OnCreate() code

        LocationBroadcastReciever lbr = new LocationBroadcastReciever();
        RegisterReceiver(lbr, new IntentFilter("test"));

    }

    public void SetButtonText(string text)
    {
        button.Text = text;
    }
}

[BroadcastReceiver]
public class LocationBroadcastReciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        /* My program never get this far, so I have not been able
           to confirm if the bellow code works or not (its from
           another example I saw). */
        //EDIT: It does NOT work. See my answer for a working example
        string text = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
        ((MainActivity)context).SetButtonText(text);
        InvokeAbortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

And in my IntentService I have this method that actually runs, but never arrives at my receiver.

```
    private void SendBroadcast(double lat, double lng, string activity)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("test");
        intent.PutExtra("title", "Updated");
        LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

This is pretty much the same code as I have in my working Android (only tweaked the BroadcastReceiver and minor adjustments to make it compile).

Can anyone see whats wrong??

**EDIT**
Finally got this whole thing to work. You can see my answer for a full, clean example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Local

You register receiver as global, but send intents via `LocalBroadcastManager`. If you want to use this manager you should register your receiver like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).RegisterReceiver(lbr, filter);
```

You can find more about `LocalBroadcastManager` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

---

## Global

Or if you want to use global broadcasts, you should create intent by type:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LocationBroadcastReciever));
```

and send it via android `Context` (in your service):

```
this.SendBroadcast(intent);
```

Also you can use intent with action, but it requires `IntentFilter` attribute on your receiver:

```
[IntentFilter(new []{ "test" })]
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class LocationBroadcastReciever : BroadcastReceiver { ... }
```

---

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of local and global, and also was missing the IntentFilter on BroadcastReceiver, as both answers suggested.

Comment: @mathkid91, you can find this post interesting: http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

First, you need the `[IntentFilter]` on the receiver. So it should look like....

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new [] { "test" })]
public class LocationBroadcastReciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        /* My program never get this far, so I have not been able
           to confirm if the bellow code works or not (its from
           another example I saw). */
        string text = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
        ((MainActivity)context).SetButtonText(text);
        InvokeAbortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

That should get you past your issue.

Second, you should register and unregister the reciever. So you should register in the `OnResume` and unregister in `OnPause`.

```
[Activity(Label = "GetLocation.Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    LocationBroadcastReciever _lbr;
    Button button;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // ... various OnCreate() code
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _lbr = new LocationBroadcastReciever();
        RegisterReceiver(lbr, new IntentFilter("test"));
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(_lbr);
        base.OnPause();
    }

    public void SetButtonText(string text)
    {
        button.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Note: these changes are what I saw different between your code and my code for a working broadcast receiver. Whether my changes are necessary or not, I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of future search results, here is a clean example of my code with a working BroadcastReceiver

```
// ** MainActivity
namespace GetLocation.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "GetLocation.Droid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        //I initialize my view(s) here to access them from outside of OnCreate().
        Button button;
        //I found this in an Android BroadcastReceiver example of how to access the MainActivity from the BroadcastReceiver.
        private static MainActivity ins;
        public static MainActivity getInstace()
        {
            return ins;
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
            ins = this;

            button.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyIntentService));
                StartService(intent);
            };

            LocationBroadcastReciever lbr = new LocationBroadcastReciever();
            LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).RegisterReceiver(lbr, new IntentFilter("test"));

        }

        public void SetButtonText(string text)
        {
            button.Text = text;
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "test" })]
    public class LocationBroadcastReciever : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            string text = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
            MainActivity.getInstace().SetButtonText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my IntentService

```
namespace GetLocation.Droid
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.mytos.MyIntentService" })]
    public class MyIntentService : IntentService
    {

        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            SendBroadcast("My message");
        }

        private void SendBroadcast(string message)
        {
            //Here you can of course send whatever variable you want. Mine is a string
            Intent intent = new Intent("test");
            intent.PutExtra("title", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using `LocalBroadcastManager`, you can remove `BroadcastReceiver` and `IntentFilter` attributes from your receiver. They are necessary only with global broadcasts.

Comment: @g4s8 are you sure? i think they are necessary, do you have any example?

Comment: @CDrosos, yes, as you can see here https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.IntentFilterAttribute/ `IntentFilterAttribute` generates `intent-filter` element in `AndroidManifest.xml`. But `LocalBroadcastManager` does't require manifest's intent-filter, instead of this he requires filter as argument for `registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)

Comment: so we should not put something like this [IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.mytos.MyIntentService" })] on the service?

Comment: @CDrosos, no, I've said that `[IntentFilter]` is redundant only on `BroadcastReceiver`. `[IntentFilter]` for service may be required - it's out of context in this example, services filters does not depend on broadcasts. This link may help you: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_1_-_started_services/#Starting_a_Service_With_an_Intent_Filter